# Homotopy equivalence of S1 and R2-0

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

I want to show that $X=S^1=\{x^2+y^2=1|x,y\in \mathbb{R}\}$ and $Y=\mathbb{R}^2-\{0\}$ are homotopy equivalent. For this I have to find a function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ and a function $g:Y\rightarrow X$ such that $f\circ g$ is homotopic to the $id_Y$ and  $g\circ f$ is homotopic to the $id_X$.

The construction of $g$ is easy: $g(x,y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}$.

But how do I construct $f$? There is a certain ambiguity 'how much I stretch the unit circle'?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: $f$ would just be the inclusion map. What you also have to do is to construct the required homotopies.

Comment: In fact you will have $g\circ f = \text{id}_X$, so it suffices to exhibit a homotopy $f\circ g \simeq \text{id}_Y$.

Comment: The keywords here are “deformation retract”.

Comment: Surprisingly often, the hardest problems are the ones that have infinitely many right answers rather than just a single right answer. In this case, any of the maps $(x, y) \mapsto (rx, ry)$, where $r$ is any nonzero real, will work for $f$ (as will infinitely many others!).

Comment: So it is okay, if $f$ is injective? @JohnHughes if I chose one r then my function does not hit all points in $Y$

Comment: Why does it matter that the function not hit all points of $Y$? A function that is not surjective can *still* be a homotopy equivalence. In fact no continuous function from $X$ to $Y$ is surjective, since $X$ is compact and $Y$ is not compact.

Comment: I think the problem is that I cannot show that $g\circ f$ and $id_Y$ are homotopic to each other. $g\circ f$ maps all points in $\mathbb{R}^2-\{0\}$ to a circle of radius r if $f(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}r x\\ry\end{pmatrix}$. How do I show this?

Comment: I think I answered my question on my own: To show that $g\circ f$ and $id_Y$ are homotopic I construct $H:Y\times(0,\infty]\rightarrow Y$ as $H=\frac{1}{r}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}$, correct?

Comment: Perhaps you could write your definition of $H$ a little more explicitly, like $H: Y \times [0, 1] \to Y : (y, t) \mapsto \ldots$, so that we know what the arguments to $H$ are called. Right now, what you've got is kind of meaningless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\mathbb{S}^{n} \simeq \mathbb{R}^{n+1} - \lbrace 0 \rbrace$

Indeed, consider the functions: $$f: \mathbb{R}^{n+1} - \lbrace 0 \rbrace \longrightarrow \mathbb{S}^{n}$$ and $$i : \mathbb{S}^{n} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n+1} - \lbrace 0 \rbrace$$ so defined: $f(x) = \dfrac{x}{||x||}$ and and $i$, the inclusion.

1) $(f \circ i) = \text{id}_{\mathbb{S}^{n}}$

2) $i \circ f : \mathbb{R}^{n+1} - \lbrace 0 \rbrace \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n+1} - \lbrace 0 \rbrace $ is homotopic the identity application of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1} - \lbrace 0 \rbrace$  by means of a linear homotopy, since every point $x \neq 0$ in  $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$  can be joined to the $\dfrac{x}{||x||}$ by means of a line segment which does not contain the origin. More precisely: $$H : \mathbb{R}^{n+1} - \lbrace 0 \rbrace \times I \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n+1} - \lbrace 0 \rbrace $$ is the above-mentioned linear homotopy, thus defined: $$H(x,t) = (1-t)x + tf(x)$$ note that:

3) $H(x,0) = x = \text{id}_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1} - \lbrace 0 \rbrace}$

4) $H(x,1) = f(x) = (i \circ f)(x)$

The result follows from the items $(1)$ and $(4)$.

Comment: Perfect answer by Allan Ramos